# Renci SSH.NET - script hangs indefinitly

Tags: powershell, ssh.net

Here is the code - hangs after last command:

```
$DllPath = "Q:\A_FILES\PowerSHell\SSH_NET_for_powershell\Renci.SshNet_Binary\Renci.SshNet.dll"
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFrom( (Resolve-Path $DllPath) )
$SshClient = New-Object Renci.SshNet.SshClient('199.12.13.44', 22, 'userid', 'password')
$SshClient.Connect()
Get-Process | Out-File -FilePath D:\Powershell\SAN_NAP01_TEST.txt -Encoding ASCII
$SshCommand = $SshClient.RunCommand('statistics show-periodic')
```

The command issued via SSH above  - `STATISTICS show-periodic`  - when manually issued to an SSH session into the Netapp Storage SAN - starts displaying data and runs forever - you are not given a prompt again - you must manually issue `CTRL-C` to exit this command and then you receive the CLI prompt in the SSH session to issue another desired command. I assume this is why the powerscript hangs - because the command does not go back to a prompt - without a `CTRL-C` issued.

I would like to issue `$SshCommand = $SshClient.RunCommand('CTRL-C')` following the above last command (after a desired sleep time) - but the powershell script does not get control back.

Wondering if their is any way  to get control back  after the `statistics...` command and then be able to issue the `CTRL-C` command into the SSH session after a desired time interval.

Answer (score 0):

are you connecting to a Netapp server?

If that's the case you could consider using the -iterations parameter in your command, so your statistics command returns.

```
$SshCommand = $SshClient.RunCommand('statistics show-periodic -iterations 5')
```